# How to link to a numbered shared library?

Tags: make, gcc, libraries, dynamic-linking, shared-library

This is the command I am running

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wall -Wl,--verbose -mthumb -mthumb-interwork  -D_REENTRANT -oTestRun11 ./main.c -ldl -lpthread  -lRTU_Module
```

Which gives in the printout

```
attempt to open /lib/owasys/libRTU_Module.so failed
attempt to open /lib/owasys/libRTU_Module.a failed
```

The library is in the specified folder, but it has a numbering attached to it.

```
root@arm:/lib/owasys# ls
libFMS_Module.so.0.0.1   libGSM_Module.so.0.0.0   libIOs_Module.so.0.0.0
libGPS2_Module.so.0.0.1  libINET_Module.so.0.0.0  libRTU_Module.so.0.0.0
```

Is there a way to specify which version to chose, or alternatively specify to select any numbering version that begins with `RTU_Module`?

Otherwise if someone could suggest what could be the reason for not being able to link successfully this way.

Thank you